# Prevent span within header from creating a new line

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

Having a problem with the FAQ section of my website. I want the glyphicons to not drop onto a new line by themselves. Have tried using `&nbsp` after the question mark but that doesn't work. Have tried putting the span outside the header element but that doesn't work. Have tried flexbox but can't seem to get the layout right.

Originally I had the glyphicon as a pseduo ::after element on the header itself, and this prevented it dropping onto a line on it's own, but also prevented me using the CSS animation which I would like to keep. Dropping with the last word as well is fine, but on their own they look a bit out of place.

[Current problem shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMHDe.png)

HTML:

```
<a href="#qu5" data-toggle="collapse" class="question-anchor collapsed">
    <h3 class="question">Can I order over the telephone?<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span></h3>
</a>
<div id="qu5" class="collapse">
    <p class="answer">For child safeguarding reasons, we are unable to take telephone orders.  Please place your <a href="">order online</a> using the barcode and passcode printed on your proof card.</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.question::before {
    content: "Q.";
    font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.question-anchor span.glyphicon {
    transition: 0.3s transform ease-in-out;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.question-anchor.collapsed span.glyphicon {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.answer::before {
    content: "A.";
    font-family: 'Kalam', cursive;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: You mean the down arrow icon correct?

Comment: Yes, the down arrow. When it was a pseduo ::after element I used javascript to change the class to show the up arrow after being clicked, but had to change it to a span to get the animation working.